# How to fix angular4 muliselect dropdown error?

Tags: angular

When I try to publish my project I got below error. 
../node_modules/ng-multiselect-dropdown/ng-multiselect-dropdown.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3.
I am using anular 4. How to resolve this?
I reinstall npm, still it persists.

In package.json it is as "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",

Comment: Can you show the piece of  `package.json` where `ng-multiselect-dropdown` is placed?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngx-multi-select-dropdown`:

for later angular versions:

```
npm i ngx-multi-select-dropdown
```

Comment: npm i ngx-multi-select-dropdown ---is it for angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

You try to use with angular 3 library in Angular 4.

Incompatibility between versions causes an error.

You may consider using:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: I try was try with "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.4". But still it is persists